# SSH connection works but does not change which machine I control

Tags: networking, server, ssh

First of all, sorry if my technical terminologies are off, I hope I can make myself understood anyway.

I have this weird problem with SSH. I have 3 computers which connect to each other, the server and two clients. One of the clients connects just fine to the server but the other does not. When I write `ssh "servername"` I get prompted to enter password. I enter my password and it returns exactly the same result as when I make a successful connection from the other client. With this client, however, the text which usually says `username@clientmachinename:/$` does not change to the `username@servermachinename:/$` as it does with the other client. I can connect from the server to both of the clients without problem.

Comment: Ubuntu releases/versions?

Comment: Does it really not change the machine - or does it just not change the prompt? Do you have a `~/.ssh/config` file that defines a host address or IP for `servername`?

Comment: Use `ssh -v servername`. Use `hostname` to see where you are.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I keep my hostnames in /etc/hosts. I do not define my hosts in a config-file, in fact that file appears not to exists, but then again it doesn't do that on the machines who are bale to connect either.

Comment: Ops! Apparently ENTER posts the comment rather than making a new line. 

Using hostname show that I'm still on the local machine, although when using ctrl+d it returns a message that "Connection to servername closed". 

Using ssh -v servername yields the same result.

Comment: Current version is 20.04.2

Comment: How are you mapping hostnames to ip addresses?  Did you put them in /etc/hosts ?  Is it possible you have a mismatch there?